# Kotlin java String.format array value set

Tags: kotlin

I want this code refactoring.
if size == 5... i don't want add code.
just use for loop or stream or other solution as size args set.

```kotlin
private fun formatTest(args: List<String>): String {
    var size = args?.size
    return when {
        size == 1 -> java.lang.String.format(code.message, args[0])
        size == 2 -> java.lang.String.format(code.message, args[0], args[1])
        size == 3 -> java.lang.String.format(code.message, args[0], args[1], args[2])
        size == 4 -> java.lang.String.format(code.message, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3])
        else -> java.lang.String.format(code.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realised that I might have interpreted the question wrongly. Do you mean you want an easy way to "continue the pattern" for _all values_ of `size`, or do you mean you want to refactor the code shown as it is? My answer is for the latter interpretation, but if you actually want the former, it's trivial to adapt anyway.

Answer (score 4):

First, convert the list to an array, then use the [`*` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#spread-operator-expressions) to "spread" the array into the varargs.

```
private fun formatTest(args: List<String>) =
    if (args.size < 5) {
        String.format(code.message, *args.toTypedArray())
    } else {
        code.message
    }
```